# Can't load images with local js library

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

I'm developping an android application and I'm using local html files, therefore I use the js libraries and css's locally. The problem is that they refer to relative images on the web, I download them and try to refer them locally as well, but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're gonna need to show some code, just saying that its not working isn't likely to solve your problem.  Show us how you're trying to download them from the web/use them locally

Comment: In the html file:
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
  
  <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="codiqa.ext.css">
  
  <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->
  <script src="codiqa.ext.js"></script>

the libraries are in the same folder. The way I try to add the image is in jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css including background-image:url(/images/icons-18-white.png). The image is located in the subfolder images ofc.